# why am I having this error while using replace methode

Tags: powershell

I am trying to list first and second level folders of a path. the script works fine, but I am having this error "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression." any idea why ?

```
$folderPath = '\\FILSERVER\DATA$'
$PathScript = "C:\Users\adm\Desktop\Script_V.2"
$sites = "Madrid"
foreach ($site in $Sites){

#Get_Level_1_Folders
$PathShare = "\\FILSERVER\DATA$\Data_$site"
Get-ChildItem -Path $PathShare -Directory -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object FullName | out-file "${PathScript}\level_1_${site}.txt"
(get-content "${PathScript}\level_1_${site}.txt") -notmatch "--------" | out-file "${PathScript}\level_1_${site}.txt"
(get-content "${PathScript}\level_1_${site}.txt").replace("\\FILSERVER\DATA$\Data_$site\","" ) | out-file "${PathScript}\level_1_${site}.txt"
(get-content "${PathScript}\level_1_${site}.txt") -notmatch "FullName" | out-file "${PathScript}\level_1_${site}.txt"
(get-content "${PathScript}\level_1_${site}.txt") | Foreach {$_.TrimEnd()} | Set-Content "${PathScript}\level_1_${site}.txt"
(get-content "${PathScript}\level_1_${site}.txt") | ? {$_.trim() -ne "" } | set-content "${PathScript}\level_1_${site}.txt"

#Get_Level_2_Folders
$Level_Folders = get-content "${PathScript}\level_1_${site}.txt"
foreach($lv1 in $Leve1_Folders){
Get-ChildItem -Path $PathShare\$lv1 -Directory -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object FullName | out-file "${PathScript}\level_2_${site}_${lv1}.txt"
(get-content "${PathScript}\level_2_${site}_${lv1}.txt") -notmatch "--------" | out-file "${PathScript}\level_2_${site}_${lv1}.txt"
(get-content "${PathScript}\level_2_${site}_${lv1}.txt").replace("\\FILSERVER\DATA$\Data_$site\","") |  out-file "${PathScript}\level_2_${site}_${lv1}.txt"
(get-content "${PathScript}\level_2_${site}_${lv1}.txt") -notmatch "FullName" | out-file "${PathScript}\level_2_${site}_${lv1}.txt"
(get-content "${PathScript}\level_2_${site}_${lv1}.txt") | Foreach {$_.TrimEnd()} | Set-Content "${PathScript}\level_2_${site}_${lv1}.txt"
(get-content "${PathScript}\level_2_${site}_${lv1}.txt") | ? {$_.trim() -ne "" } | set-content "${PathScript}\level_2_${site}_${lv1}.txt"
}
```

Comment: Add the full error so we can see what it is saying is $null

Comment: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:22 char:1
+ (get-content "${PathScript}\level_2_${site}_${lv1}.txt").replace("\\s ...
+ 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:22 char:1
+ (get-content "${PathScript}\level_2_${site}_${lv1}.txt").replace("\\s ...
+ 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: the ligne causing problem is : 

(get-content "${PathScript}\level_2_${site}_${lv1}.txt").replace("\\FILSERVER\DATA$\Data_$site\","") |  out-file "${PathScript}\level_2_${site}_${lv1}.txt"

Comment: @AbdelkrimBalaboula it means that the string `"${PathScript}\level_2_${site}_${lv1}.txt"` resolved to a file name of a file that's empty

Comment: exactly, thoses files were empty, that why .. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, the cause is likely that this expandable string:

```
"${PathScript}\level_2_${site}_${lv1}.txt"
```

... resolved to the path of a file that's *empty*.

`Get-Content` will open the file - which is why you don't get any "file not found" errors - and then immediately return without outputting anything, since there's no meaningful "lines" to consume in an empty file.

The result of the `(Get-Content ...)` expression is therefore `$null`, and you received the error in question.

You can either use the `-replace` operator which will take *any number of strings* (including none) as input - just make sure you escape the arguments:

```
(Get-Content "${PathScript}\level_2_${site}_${lv1}.txt") -replace [regex]::Escape("\\FILSERVER\DATA$\Data_$site\") |Out-File ...
```

Or let the pipeline take care of enumerating the output instead of relying on implicit property enumeration:

```
Get-Content "${PathScript}\level_2_${site}_${lv1}.txt" |ForEach-Object {$_.Replace("\\FILSERVER\DATA$\Data_$site\","")} |Out-File ...
```